# Give two distinct codes for $n = 4 $

Tags: hamiltonian-path

gray codes for $n = 4 $.

Attempt :
The  codes for $n = 4 $  :

$0000, 0001, 0010, 0011, 0100, 0101, 0110, 0111, 1000, 1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101, 1110, 1111$

$0000, 0001, 0011, 0010, 0110, 0111, 0101, 0100, 1100, 1101, 1111, 1110, 1010, 1011, 1001, 1000$

Is the answer true for my question ? Anyone can give me an example about  codes, i am still not clear about it.

Comment: @MikePierce I just edited, it just exclamation mark

Comment: In a Gray code, each successive string differs from the previous by a single changed bit.  This is not true of your first code: $0001$ and $0010$ have two bits different.

Comment: @DanUznanski I learn from this site http://www.icodeguru.com/Embedded/Hacker's-Delight/090.htm. Do you have any reference about this question ?

Answer (score 1):

In the binary codes, the term distance is defined as:

> **Distance:** Number of bits which one bitstring differs from another bitstring.

For example:
$$
\begin{align}
d(0010,0011) &= 1 \mbox{ (different bits)} \\
d(1010,0011) &= 2 \mbox{ (different bits)} \\
d(1111,0000) &= 4 \mbox{ (different bits)} \\
\end{align}
$$

---

Now, it is good to remember that the order in which is defined a code is extremely important. This is because the concept of code is precisely encode a set of symbols in others.

**So, never lose sight that the order of a code is important.**

---

Your problem then lies in the definition of gray code:

> **Gray Code-$n$:** is that **two consecutive bitstrings** should **always** have distance equals to 1.

Again, order is importante here to define *"consecutive bitstrings"*. In this way, you can build a Gray code of $n=4$ (in red, the bit that diffiers from one bitstring to each consecutive bitstring):
$$
\begin{matrix}
\mbox{Hex Code} & \mbox{Gray Code} & & & & & & \mbox{Hex Code} & \mbox{Gray Code} \\
\hline
0 & 0000 & & & & & & 8 & {\color{red} 1}100 \\
1 & 000{\color{red} 1} & & & & & & 9 & 110{\color{red} 1} \\
2 & 00{\color{red} 1}1 & & & & & & A & 11{\color{red} 1}1 \\
3 & 001{\color{red} 0} & & & & & & B & 111{\color{red} 0} \\
4 & 0{\color{red} 1}10 & & & & & & C & 1{\color{red} 0}10 \\
5 & 011{\color{red} 1} & & & & & & D & 101{\color{red} 1} \\
6 & 01{\color{red} 0}1 & & & & & & E & 10{\color{red} 0}1 \\
7 & 010{\color{red} 0} & & & & & & F & 100{\color{red} 0} \\
\end{matrix}
$$

---

If you look carefully , this code actually has an interesting property is that a Gray code of $n$, can be generated from a reflection of a Gray code of $n-1$. By example, Gray code $n=1$:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\mbox{Hex Code} & \mbox{Gray Code} \\
\hline
0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
This generates Gray code $n=2$ (blue the *reflected bits*, green the *fill bits*):
$$
\begin{matrix}
\mbox{Hex Code} & \mbox{Gray Code} \\
\hline
0 & {\color{green}0}{\color{blue} 0} \\
1 & {\color{green}0}{\color{blue} 1} \\
\hline
2 & {\color{green}1}{\color{blue} 1} \\
3 & {\color{green}1}{\color{blue} 0} \\
\end{matrix}
$$
And this generates Gray code $n=3$ (blue the *reflected bits*, green the *fill bits*):
$$
\begin{matrix}
\mbox{Hex Code} & \mbox{Gray Code} \\
\hline
0 & {\color{green}0}{\color{blue}0}{\color{blue}0} \\
1 & {\color{green}0}{\color{blue}0} {\color{blue}1} \\
2 & {\color{green}0}{\color{blue}1} {\color{blue}1} \\
3 & {\color{green}0}{\color{blue}1} {\color{blue}0} \\
\hline
4 & {\color{green}1}{\color{blue}1} {\color{blue}0} \\
5 & {\color{green}1}{\color{blue}1} {\color{blue}1} \\
6 & {\color{green}1}{\color{blue}0} {\color{blue}1} \\
7 & {\color{green}1}{\color{blue}0}{\color{blue}0} \\
\end{matrix}
$$
And go on...

Comment: You can start with $0\to0000$ and generate one gray code for $n=4$.
Or you can start with $0\to0001$, and generate other gray code for $n=4$. But both codes doesn't the same, because for one code $0$ *is equivalent* to $0000$, and for other code $0$ *is equivalent* to $0001$. So, you two different Gray codes for $n=4$.
Again, order is important.

Comment: No, doesn't. See this example. The first gray code:

$$0000,0001,0011,0010,0110,0111,0101,0100,1100,1101,1111,1110,1010,1011,1001,1000$$

Other gray code:

$$0001,0011,0010,0110,0111,0101,0100,1100,1101,1111,1110,1010,1011,1001,1000,0000$$

See that this last gray code starts with $0001$ and ends with $0000$, and the sequence is the same, but code doesn't the same because encoded $0\to 0000$ in first gray code and $0\to 0001$ in second gray code. You understand?

Comment: yes, I got it now. Thank you

Comment: Your welcome! :)